# Weird graphical issue in Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, intel-graphics, screen, 20.10, visual-artifacts

I installed Xubuntu 20.10 on my old Acer Aspire AX1400B4702 computer recently and it works great, except for one thing: every time I try to launch an app I just installed, the screen shows some weird glitches.

[image: screen glitches]

The computer runs on integrated graphics.

I've done some research, but I did not find anything useful. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You're right. That is a weird bug. How about giving us some more information? [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1299919/edit) your question to let us know what graphics card driver you're using, what version of Xubuntu you're using, what you've already tried, and things like that. Help us help you.

Comment: What is the app that you installed?  Is it a full-screen program?  Is it trying to replace xfwm4?

Comment: I dont know but every newly installed apps does that when i launch them for the first time.